# Screen goes black randomly for 1 sec (18.04 bionic beaver)

Tags: display, intel-graphics, screen

Just installed 18.04 on a desktop and every few seconds the screen goes black for 1-2 seconds then comes back to life! (Not the computer, just the screen because if I keep typing then everything is still there).

This happens more when I am downloading/installing things.

I have had 14.04 and 16.04 installed before on this computer but never had this problem.

- processor: Intel(R)Core:i5-3470@3.20Ghz
- motherboard:HP 3397
- graphics: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen

Comment: Did you figure out why? I too am facing the same issue.

Comment: Hi @Megh that was in my old work computer and as far as I remember it was a graphic card issue. Do you also have a similar intel graphic card?